# How to get the background color of a button or label (QPushButton, QLabel) in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, uibackgroundcolor

I am quite new to PyQt. Does anyone tell me how to get the background color of a button or label (QPushButton, QLabel) in PyQt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used PyQt, but I think API should be very similar to C++. To get background color of QWidget-based class, first get its [palette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#palette-prop) and then call [QPalette::color()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpalette.html#color-2) with [QPalette::Window](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) role.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a sample code. This will help you.

```
QPushButton button1, button2;
button1.setStyleSheet("background-color:#ff0000;");

//To get Background color
QColor color = button1.palette().button().color();

//To set fetched color
button2.setStyleSheet("background-color:" + color.name() +";");
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.show()

myLabel = QLabel()
colorOfmyLabel = myLabel.palette().window().color().name()
print(colorOfmyLabel)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the output:

```
#f0f0f0
```