# How to get the background color of QT-toolButton/pushButton using C++

Tags: qt, qtoolbutton

**Related Qusetions:**

- [How to get widget background QColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519749/how-to-get-widget-background-qcolor) `QWidget::palette().color(QWidget::backgroundRole())`
- [How to get background color of a dialog/window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473525/how-to-get-background-color-of-a-dialog-window)
- [Qt QPlainTextEdit background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528685/qt-qplaintextedit-background/1532179#1532179)

There are at least 3 ways to solve the problem:

```
// 1st 
QColor color = ui->toolButton->palette().color(QWidget::backgroundRole());
// 2nd
QColor color = ui->toolButton->palette().background().color();
// 3rd
QColor color = colorSetting = ui->toolButton->palette().color(QPalette::Window);
```

---

**Update:** sorry I have made some mistakes, both of the following ways work well.

---

**Raw Qusetion:**

I have tried

```
QColor color = ui->toolButton->palette().background().color();
```

and

```
QColor color = colorSetting = ui->toolButton->palette().color(QPalette::Window);
```

both got `QColor(ARGB 1, 0.941176, 0.941176, 0.941176)`, not the right color I want.

The background color is set by editing `mainwindow.ui`, change stylesheet of toolButton
to `background-color: rgb(255, 170, 255);`

[image of my toolButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqrFt.png)

and for pyQt, see here [How to get the background color of a button or label (QPushButton, QLabel) in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271366/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-a-button-or-label-qpushbutton-qlabel-in-py)

Answer (score 0):

Your linked question is incorrect about the color role used by buttons. You are looking for `QPalette::Button` as your [`ColorRole`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum).

```
QColor color = ui->toolbutton->palette()->color(QPalette::Button);
```

Be are that this color *may not represent the background painted for the tool button*. Some styles use gradients and `QPalette` stores brushes, not colors. Call `QPalette::button()` to retrieve the button background brush.

I suspect you intend to change the background color. You can call [`setBrush()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#setBrush-1) to set it:

```
//Create a solid brush of the desired color
QBrush brush(someColor);
//Get a copy of the current palette to modify
QPalette pal = ui->toolbutton->palette();
//Set all of the color roles but Disabled to our desired color
pal.setBrush(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Button, brush);
pal.setBrush(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Button, brush);
//And finally set the new palette
ui->toolbutton->setPalette(pal);
```